# C# Async Socket, BeginReceive method does not start a new thread

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have an async server socket listener and thousands clients.
The below code working as expected until some time (which is differ some time is 1 hour, some time is 3 days.), then not accept new connections. When this event happens, my process is still working and the port which server listen showing still listening on Resource Monitoring. I use wireshark to determine to client connections in this period.

So I add some logs to find reason, why? I cache some things but I don't know what trigger that. My detection that `BeginReceive` does not start a new thread and current thread keep working on my `OnClientConnected` method. Therefore, the server doesn't accept any new connection.

```
    protected Socket listener;
    protected ManualResetEvent acceptDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void Start(int port) {
        try {
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
            LingerOption myOpts = new LingerOption(false, 0);
            listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, myOpts);
            listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);

            listener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100000);
            Logger.Info(
                $"{ServiceInformation.LocalIpAddress}:{port} listining.");
            StartListening();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Error(
                $"{ServiceInformation.LocalIpAddress}:{port} not listening.",
                e);
        }
    }

    private void StartListening() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Logger.Info("StartListening acceptdone reset." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    acceptDone.Reset();

                    Logger.Info("StartListening begin accept." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    listener.BeginAccept(OnClientConnected, listener);

                    Logger.Info("StartListening acceptdone waitone." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    acceptDone.WaitOne();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.Error("StartListening error." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Error("while error" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, e);
        }
    }

    protected void OnClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
        acceptDone.Set();
        Logger.Info("OnClientConnected acceptdone set." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        //I am expecting here to changing current thread id. If it change my listener working. 

        Socket client;
        try {
            var _listener = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            client = _listener.EndAccept(asyncResult);
            Logger.Info($"Client connected: {client.RemoteEndPoint}" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        } catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
            Logger.Error($"Listening socket has been closed." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return;
        }

        try {
            var state = GetStateObject(client);

            client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, OnMessageReceived, state);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Error($"Listening socket has been closed.", e);
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        Logger.Info("OnClientConnected finish.");
    }
```

Comment: Your assumption that the thread id will always change is not always trye, IMO. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept) the calling thread may be used to call the callback synchronously. Something else may be going on (i.e it´s failing at some other point)

Comment: You are right about according th docs case. However, I am observing and loging about 2 weeks. Some thing happend after that case. Now, my listener working syncronously well. But I am not understand why it is happen? Edit: Besides according the docs said 'completed syncronously' , how I will coding to working like .Accept method?

Comment: My understanding is that you don´t need to change anything. If it completed synchronously, the callback was called in the same thread, that´s all.

Comment: My experience is that when callback called same thread, new coming client connection does not accepting. My problem is starting here. I receive message and send message with some logic and receive again...

Comment: So your theory is that the EndAccept call is not completing and blocking the listener thread, if I understand you correctly? Maybe enabling tracing would help.

Comment: My point is that when the EndAccept not completed successfully or some how, I am not sure about here, the listening thread wait long time. Clients trying to connect, I observing via wireshark, but my listener not accept a new client. At test envoriment I do enable tracing but I could not enable at production. At test there is no problem, I use Apache JMeter and client count more than production. I think there are several reason. 1. My server computer, 2. C# not handle async all successfully (because sync is working great), 3. My code or desing is wrong, I am not sure